# rich:scrollableDataTable with a 2 row header

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jstl, seam

I'm developping a scrollableDataTable with an header having 2 row in it.

```
<rich:scrollableDataTable ...
 <rich:column...>
  <f:facet name="header">
   <s:div>
    <h:panelGrid columns="1">
     <h:outputText value="Hi" />
     <h:outputText value="all" />
    </h:panelGrid>
   </s:div>
  </f:facet>
  ...
 </rich:column>
```

But I only see 'Hi' on video. In the html produced I see both rows, infact looking better in the html code using a web-browser-debug (F12) I see the header of the column has an height fixed to 20px or 21px.

To see my second header-row I must enlarge it changing (using web-browser-debug):
.rich-sdt-header-cell-body (height : 40px)
GridBodyTemplate (top: 42px)
header:NormalBox (height: 42px)
GridHeaderTemplate (height: 42px)

How can I do this in my xhtml? Other scrollableDataTable&columns have header composed by an only one row (and goes well for me). I only need, in only one situation, have an header more taller. Is it possible, and how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved adding "headerClass" tag to rich:column.
In this way I can specify the height of the header row (rows) and even other things.